# jQuery beforeunload and areYouSure jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I found that we can use  two commonly used functions to stop propagating before leaving the unsaved data

- beforeunload
- areYouSure - jquery plugin

Both of the above can be used. following is the minor code i tested

```
 <script>
 $(function() {

    $('#form').data('serialize',$('#form').serialize()); // On load save form current state

    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){                       // binding the beforeunload
        if($('#form').serialize()!= $('#form').data('serialize'))
            return true; 
        else 
            e=null; // i.e; if form state change show warning box, else don't show it.
    });

</script>
```

> Note: i am unbinding the function for save button to hide the warning
>   same code i tested for **areYouSure**

so now my question is, am i following the correct approach, and which one is better efficiency wise ?

Comment: What do you mean with "efficiency"? The plugin also uses the "beforeunload" event under the hood, but I guess it has a bit more extra functionality...

Comment: Plugin's better

Comment: @MarioDS - yeah, i meant the efficiency